# PXE error after installing on Lenovo U410. How to solve it?

Tags: lenovo, ssd, pxe

I changed the handler in BIOS from RAID to AHCI, and then installed Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 on 32 GB SSD.

I am getting an error every time when I boot:

> PXE Device not found check the cable.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, Ubuntu 12.10 (or any Linux) needs a `efi` partition also if the BIOS has `UEFI` booting technology.

Answer (score 0):

Set the computer not tro try to boot from the network and this message should vanish.

Comment: I was unable to find an option to disable it in BIOS. Under which menu can I find it ?

Comment: That is different per bios, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Make PXE Boot disable from BIOS, So you will not get such error. In most of system DEl or F2 opens BIOS. You just need to know you motherboard details for that.